# Why need weak self in block?

Tags: ios, block

Just like the following code:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self methodThatTakesABlock:^ {
    [weakSelf doSomething];
    //[self doSomething];//Why not this line?
}];
```

Comment: because if `self` is not explicitly weak, then it's strong, in which case it causes a retain cycle, leading to memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self methodThatTakesABlock:^ {
    [self doSomething];
}];
```

Does **not** cause a retain cycle unless the completion block is stored within `self`. If it is a property then, `self` will have a strong reference to the block and the block will have a strong reference to `self` causing a retain cycle. That is why you need to use `weak`, to avoid this retain cycle. But remember, you must use a weak self only within blocks that are stored as properties or ivars within self.

If the completion block is only called in the `methodThatTakesABlock` then you don't have to use a weak self since the block is not retained. In this case, the block will have a strong reference to `self` but self will not have one towards the block, so no retain cycle in this case.

Comment: That's not the only case that causes a retain cycle when strong `self` is used within blocks.